# Pause the HTML5 video when space bar is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have this script which should pause the HTML5 video when space bar is pressed. Bur in Firefox it pauses on all keys you press no matter is space or other and in Chrome it doesen't work at all.

Also double clicking the video doesen't go to full screen.

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 0) {
    if (video.paused == true)
            video.play();
        else
            video.pause();
  }
});


$video.dblclick(function() {
    video.mozRequestFullScreen();
   video. webkitRequestFullscreen();
   video.requestFullscreen();
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6f7navgu/4/

Comment: `double clicking the video doesn't go to full screen` Why would it go fullscreen automatically? This is not YouTube.

Comment: Does that mean that youtube has copyright / patent on the technique (particularly on pausing on space bar)? All of the video playback software that I have come across don't support pausing using space-bar which given the attention to user-experience,  could be assumed as being a standard feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the snippet below

```
var video = document.getElementById('video_id');   
document.onkeypress = function(e){
    if((e || window.event).keyCode === 32){
        video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
    }
};
```

To have the video in fullscreen mode, use the following one

```
var video = document.getElementById("video_id");
document.ondblclick = function(){
    if(video.requestFullscreen){
        video.requestFullscreen();
    }else if(video.mozRequestFullScreen){
        video.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }else if(video.webkitRequestFullscreen){
        video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
};
```

Working [jsBinl](http://jsbin.com/regakeminapi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: jQuery version?

Answer (score 2):

Use `keyup` and `Event.keyCode === 32` instead. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f7navgu/16/)

If you like, you could use `keydown` as well in this case, because you're not testing for an input value.

Answer (score 1):

Double clicking wouldn't go to full screen; you would have to add that action. As for pause, try `which` property of the jQuery event.

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    // debugger;
    if (e.which == 32) {
        if (video.paused == true)
            video.play();
        else
            video.pause();
    }
});
```

Uncomment the debugger so that you can inspect the event that happened.

Comment: @dandavis - haha, think its getting late. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is jquery and it pause and plays video with space and on video window click:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            $('#videoID').click(function(){this.paused?this.play() :this.pause();});
            $(window).keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode === 32) {
            $('#videoID').get(0).paused?$('#videoID').get(0).play() :$('#videoID').get(0).pause();
            }
            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
        video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
    }
});
video.ondblclick = function(){
        video.requestFullscreen();
};
```